# Do communal and individual prayers correspond to different sacrifices?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, korban

Prayer, in general, is compared to the sacrifices that were offered in the Temple, as alluded to in [Hoshea 14:3](http://chabad.org/16168#v=3&showrashi=true).

But, halacha distinguishes between the prayers of an individual (תפלה ביחיד) and the prayers of the community (תפלה בצבור).

Do these different types of prayer relate to different types of sacrifices and if so, how?

Comment: Well, there are individual (קרבן יחיד) and communal (קרבן ציבור) sacrifices too. How precise a correspondence are you looking for?

Comment: If you have sources, I'm open to hear about both. It seems relevant and worth knowing.

Comment: Somewhat related. I heard a shiur years ago, possibly from R' Doniel Landers(?) who said a chidush and IIRC said Rav Soleveitchik had said this idea. It mashes up the gemara a bit so double check the gemara before deciding if you like it or not. The quite amida is what the gemara refers to when saying the amid a was nisaken kineged the avos. The chazaras hashatz is kineged the public communal offering. I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but once you're on the subject.....

Comment: @user6591: I'm assuming from your reference to the Avot (Avraham, Yitzchok and Yaacov) that you are making the connection to Shacharit, Mincha and Ma'ariv. But they didn't have a korban at night.

Comment: That works out well. We only have chazzaras hashatz by shacharis and mincha, kineged the two karban tamid. The fact that we have three silent amidos is kineged the three avos.

Comment: Yes, but the tefillah b'Tzibbur is both during the day and at night. And that isn't even touching on what Double AA brought up in regard to the association with the  individual and communal offerings. Hoshea doesn't seem to limit the connection to communal offerings.

Comment: @Yaacov again, I am not discussing Teffila bitzibur as you are, that is a different idea. I am merely mentioning a related point, the Teffila OF the tzibur, which I thought you might find interesting.

Comment: @YD I believe that the Maariv "Korban" is the fact that the limbs of the daytime offerings were burned all night.

Comment: @DavidKenner: the remnants from the days offerings that burned overnight was not a new korban. Offerings were only made during the day as is understood from Mishna Zevachim, chapter 5. Their time begins in the day.

Comment: @YD That's why I put Korban in quotes. I think it is still nevertheless connected to the burning of the limbs at night.

Comment: @YD Looking it up in the Gemara Brachos 26b, a Braisa supporting R' Yehoshuah ben Levi, says that Ma'ariv corresponds to the burning of the limbs and fats. Rashi holds this to be the limbs of an Olah whose blood was offered before sundown in general; or the fats of any Korban all year round. (whose blood was offered before sundown)  Rambam and Tur  hold it was the leftover afternoon Tamid.

Comment: @DavidKenner, It emphasizes that the Maariv prayer does not have a corresponding korban like Shacharit and Mincha. The braisa says ומפני מה אמרו תפלת הערב? אין לה קבע! שהרי אברים ופדרים שלא נתעכלו מבערב, קרבים והולכים כל הלילה. In other words, it isn't a different korban. It's only if the korban of Mincha had not had time to be completely consumed that it was permissible to continue burning it all night. It had already been offered, meaning the semicha and shechita at mincha. So in terms of korbanot, Ma'ariv would be optional, not obligatory. It could be said if needed. But it isn't optional.

Comment: @DavidKenner As I think about this citation, it is of interest to note that at the top of the page it mentions how Ma'ariv was set to correspond to the prayer of Yaacov Avinu. It says this comes from Bereshit 28:11 which uses the expression "ויפגע במקום" and says that "פגע" means prayer. Rabbeinu Avraham ben HaRambam in Sefer HaMaspik l'Ovdei HaShem, chapter on hitbodedut says this same root is a synonym to 'isolation' (בדד). That would mean the Ma'ariv prayer is intended as an individual prayer. This ties back to DoubleAA's comment above about (קרבן יחיד) and (קרבן ציבור).

Comment: @user6591 if the idea is that the silent aminda is kneged avos and the chazarah is kneged korbanos, why is there a silent amida for musaf?

Comment: @Danno that's a good question. But perhaps there is a blanketed takana where there is no loud rendition without a silent one. Although the opposite situation by maariv would possibly prove this wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rav Yosef Dov Ber Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik) mentions this topic in the essay פסוקי דזמרה in volume 2 of שעורים לזכר אבא מרי ז״ל ([pages 36-38](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?155163&lang=eng)). He asks:

1. Since we say that required prayer (תפילת חובה) corresponds to bringing the *tamid* offering (קרבן תמיד), and the latter must come from *all* Israel, how could it be that a *minyan* that does not include all of Israel bring such an offering?
2. Even stronger than question 1: how could an individual bring a communal offering?
3. How could it be that each minyan brings a *tamid*, when we only need one *tamid* for all Israel?

To put it simply, he explains that all the prayers of all *minyanim* and all obligatory prayers of individuals combine into one *tamid* for all of Israel. He contrasts this to a voluntary prayer (תפילת נדבה) of an individual, which is an individual offering (קרבן יחיד) "from beginning to end".

So to answer your question, according to Rav Soloveitchik, both communal prayers and individual obligatory prayers correspond to the *tamid* offering, whereas voluntary prayers of an individual correspond to individual offerings.  See the essay itself for textual support for his assertion, and more nuance/details.

Comment: Good answer. Too bad it isn't in English for those who could benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Different prayers were made to represent different offerings, but how the prayer is said or with a minyan (quorum) or not does not change what the prayer was created to represent. [there is such a thing as a tiffilot neduva (a voluntary prayer) that represents the karbon neduvah (voluntary offering)